# Call .exe from windows system service python?

Tags: python, windows

I have a Windows System Service that I am trying to write. I'm trying to an interface for a POS machine, so ideally I would like to include this code inside of the system service. However some experimentation has lead me to believe that the windows system service will only execute basic tasks and not oter iterations.

I have another function that I need to call every x seconds, this additional function is a while loop, but I cannot get my function and the win32 loop to wait for system calls to play nicely together. I go into greater detail in my code below.

```
import win32service  
import win32serviceutil  
import win32event

class PySvc(win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):  
    # net name  
    _svc_name_ = "test"  

    _svc_display_name_ = "test"  

    _svc_description_ = "Protects your computer."  

    def __init__(self, args):  
        win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self,args)  
        # create an event to listen for stop requests on  
        self.hWaitStop = win32event.CreateEvent(None, 0, 0, None)


    # core logic of the service     
    def SvcDoRun(self):


        # if the stop event hasn't been fired keep looping
        while rc != win32event.WAIT_OBJECT_0:




            # block for 60 seconds and listen for a stop event  
            rc = win32event.WaitForSingleObject(self.hWaitStop, 60000)

        ## I want to put an additional function that uses a while loop here.
        ## The service will not work correctly with additional iterations, inside or 
        ## the above api calls.    
        ## Due to the nature of the service and the api call above, 
        ## this leads me to have to compile an additional .exe and somehow call that 
        ## from the service.     

    # called when we're being shut down      

    def SvcStop(self):  
            # tell the SCM we're shutting down  
            self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)  
            # fire the stop event  
            win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitStop)  

if __name__ == '__main__':  

    win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(PySvc)
```

My research has shown me that I need to somehow call a .exe from a windows system service. Does anyone know how to do this? I have tried using os.system, and variant calls of the subprocess module to no avail, it seems that windows simply ignores them. Any ideas?

EDIT: revert to original question

Comment: It is certainly possible to launch a subprocess from a system service, but it's almost always the wrong thing to do.  Perhaps if you post a new question showing the code you were trying to use (the "additional function that uses a while loop") we could advise you on how to make it work properly?

Comment: I'm trying to create a service using pyHook that listens for 'ctrl c' input and upon reception of the input it executes further commands. The code is:

Comment: Harry Johnston - I just added the code. Do you have any ideas as to how I can get i to function properly either as a stand alone .exe or inside of the system service?

Comment: System services don't have access to the user session.

Comment: @Jorge: system services don't receive input from the keyboard.  It simply isn't possible to do that.  From the sounds of it you don't want a system service, you want a replacement shell (to run instead of explorer.exe) or perhaps just a background process (to run as well as explorer.exe).

Comment: Thanks Ignacio. I've since re edited the question again. Do you know of any api calls I could call to that would allow interaction with the user session or any ways to invoke a .exe from the SvcDoRun method or any other win32api?

Comment: Harry, thanks. I actually have 2 work arounds for this problem, one being to compile the aforementioned pyhook section into a standalone .exe and run it from the all users startup folder, another being to schedule it in at, however I'd really like to get it running from the service. Or at least the .exe invoked from the service. You said I could launch it as a subprocess, how would I do that?

Comment: @Jorge: you can launch an ordinary subprocess from a service in the same way you'd launch one from any other Python executable, but *it won't help*.  Services don't receive keyboard input, because they're not running on the active desktop.  A subprocess of a service won't magically be relocated to the active desktop.  Launching a process on the active desktop from a service is possible, but it's very difficult even for a service written in C, and there are very few advantages to launching it that way rather than from, say, the startup folder.

Comment: Thanks for the help Harry. Are you aware of any other possible registry entries that could start the .exe with the current working privs of whichever user? Or a way to start an .exe as the current user without relying on copy/paste/shortcut/at methods? I'm currently looking into the CreateProcessAsUser() win32api call that in theory should work if invoked from a system service. Will report back w/results.

Comment: And Harry, subprocess doesn't work with system services regardless of whether they recieve input or not. Looks like a security measure MS uses.

Comment: @Jorge: I've written system services that launch subprocesses.  It definitely works.  You're either experiencing a Python-specific issue or you have a bug in your code.  CreateProcessAsUser is the right approach, but it's not trivial to get a copy of the user's token to use.  See http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowssecurity/thread/31bfa13d-982b-4b1a-bff3-2761ade5214f

Comment: Also http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314866

Comment: I was referring to the python module called 'subprocess'. If anyone else is having this same problem consider at & the all user startup folder as temp solutions as using subprocess, popen, os to run a .exe will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Can't say as I'm familiar with Windows development but in *nix I've found sockets are very useful in situations where two things shouldn't be able to talk by definition but you need them to anyway e.g. making web browsers launch desktop apps, making the clipboard interact with the browser etc.

In most cases UDP sockets are all that you need for a little IPC and they are trivial to code for in Python. You do have to be extra careful though, often restrictions are there for a good reason and you need to really understand a rule before you go breaking it... Bear in mind anyone can send a UDP packet so make sure the receiving app only accept packets from localhost and make sure you sanity check all incoming packets to protect against local hackers/malware. If the data transmitted is particularly sensitive or the action initiated is powerful it may not be a good idea at all, only you know your app well enough to say really.

Comment: How is this relevant to the OPs question?  That is, how would IPC help him?

Comment: @HarryJohnston - If the main part of his code is running in a restricted context and that is preventing him from running a particular subprocess directly then he could run a small shim in a less restrictive context and communicate with it via sockets.